# ¿Como puedo poner un select option con varios modal de bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, modal

Hola a todos como estáis, espero que me puedan ayudar por favor ya que estoy intentando poner varios `option` con distintas ventanas emergentes o modal pero no he podido, ya que al momento de seleccionar alguna opción no ocurre nada.

A continuación les muestro lo que tengo para que se den una mejor idea  gracias!!!

```js
function changeFunc(id){
        
        if(id =="exampleModal"){
            $("#exampleModal").show();
            
        }else{
            document.write("no se ejecuto la funcion");
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<select name="Comb" id="Contenido" class="form-control" onchange="changeFunc(this.value);">
      <option value="0">-</option>
      <option value="exampleModal">España</option>
      <option value="44">Colombia</option>
    </select>
    
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        aqui la informacion
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: explica mejor lo que pretendes, por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las modales de **Bootstrap** se muestran a través de la función `modal('show');`.

```js
function changeFunc(id){
  if(id =="exampleModal") {
    $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
  }
  else {
    document.write("no se ejecuto la funcion");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name="Comb" id="Contenido" class="form-control" onchange="changeFunc(this.value);">
  <option value="0">-</option>
  <option value="exampleModal">España</option>
  <option value="44">Colombia</option>
</select>
    
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        aqui la informacion
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Referencia:** [Mostrar modal Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalshow)

Comment: Me funciono, Muchas gracias!! te lo agradezco en verdad